# Sbt config for test not available for test-only too

Tags: sbt

I have added in my Build.scala file a java option for running tests:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dmy.config=something",
fork in test := true,
```

This is applied when I run `sbt test` in my project. But if I run a single test file using `sbt test-only *Reports*` this java option setting is no longer taken in consideration.

Does anybody has a clue?